# Call decorated interactive function with widget arguments

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Say I created an interactive function using ipywidgets as such:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, Select

def print_fruit(fruit):
    print(fruit)

fruitSelect = Select(options=['tomato', 'banana'])

w = interactive(print_fruit, fruit=fruitSelect)
w
```

Now, I want to call print_fruit with the currently selected fruit from another function. What would be the recommended method ?(besides redoing the same work of getting the selected options from the widgets and calling print_fruit with the correct argument, which is tedious when there are many...).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current value of a widget by accessing the `.value` parameter.

So in this case, `print_fruit(fruitSelect.value)` should do it.

EDIT: For multiple widgets

Grab the widgets from w with the exception of the last one (the `Output` widgets) in a comprehension.

`print_fruit(*(widg.value for widg in w.children[:-1]))`

Comment: I'm actually hoping to not have to do this, if the function takes N arguments it's a bit tedious to have to get them all while the main widgets already has that.

Comment: Updated, didn't realise that multiple widgets was the main thrust of your question.

Comment: ha yeah that should work, thanks! I'll leave the question open in case there's a w.something method to do that directly, but I agree iterating over .children gives most of the robustness I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: (misc: in my case I'll also call w.f instead of explicitly calling print_fruit, to limit the dependencies to the interactive widget, in case someone else has the same needs...)

Comment: Worth noting if you use `fixed` arguments to an interact this approach will probably fail.